# Hyperref a subfloat figure

Tags: floats, hyperref, subfloats

Here is a sample code from my document,

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[$a=0.2$]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Chapters/BMethods/figures/Airy_Rings_0.pdf}}~~~~~&~~~~~
\subfloat[$a=1$]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Chapters/BMethods/figures/Airy_Rings_1.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[$a=2.5$]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Chapters/BMethods/figures/Airy_Rings_2.pdf}}~~~~~&~~~~~
\subfloat[$a=4$]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{Chapters/BMethods/figures/Airy_Rings_3.pdf}} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Airy rings with central Airy disk, constant $\lambda$=1 and with varying aperture factor.}
\label{Airy rings with central Airy disk}
\end{figure}
```

How can I apply `hyperref` to the `subfloat` figures , so that if I want to refer to just one of the sub figures in specific.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just add a `label` after the `subfloat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\label` after the caption.

```
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[$a=0.2$\label{fig:whatever}]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{...
```

You can the reference the figure using `\ref{fig:whatever}` in your text.

Note: I usually prefix my labels using something `fig:`, `eqn:` or similar so I can better see  what I'm referencing when I read the .tex source.

Comment: Thanks. Excellent idea there ... use fig: or eqn: so that it will is more organized. Liked that ! thanks.